# Solving "finding value" using factorisation

Tags: factoring

Even my teacher could not do this.This is a question extracted from the mathematics challenge board created by my friend in school.This is the question

> Given $x-y=3$,find the value of $x^3-2x^2y+xy^2-3xy+3y^2$

The way I do this first,is that the first 3 terms I factorise,the last 2 terms I also factorise by the highest common factor

\begin{align}
x^3-2x^2y+xy^2-3xy+3y^2 & = x(x^2-2xy+y^2)-3y(x-y)\\
& = x(x-y)^2-3y(x-y)\\
\end{align}

The problem is just,how do I get $x-3y$?

Comment: $x=y+3$ and plug it back into $x^3-2x^2y+xy^2-3xy+3y^2$, which yields [27](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y%2B3%29%5E3%E2%88%922*%28y%2B3%29%5E2*y%2B%28y%2B3%29*y%5E2%E2%88%923*%28y%2B3%29*y%2B3*y%5E2).

Comment: You don't need to find that. $x(x-y)^2 -3y(x-y) = x(3)^2 - 3y(3) =  9x -9y $

Comment: Just let y=0, x=3. Then you have x^3-2x^2y+xy^2-3xy+3y^2=            x^3+y(-2x^2+xy-3x+3y)=x^3+0=27

Comment: @user222031 wow...BWAHAHAAHA IM SO DUMB

Comment: @hkmather802 That is a very cool math trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user222031 pointed out, you can substitute the value of the given expression into your last expression, which makes it much easier to continue simplifying:

\begin{align}
x(x-y)^2-3y(x-y)&=x(3)^2-3y(3) \\
&=9x-9y \\
&=9(x-y) \\
&=27
\end{align}

Alternatively, as Mythomorphic suggested, you can assign any values to $x$ and $y$ such that $x-y=3$ and then directly evaluate the expression.